# Can the subject appear at the head of a relative clause and **in** the clause simultaneously?

Tags: grammar, parsing, relative-clauses

> 宮城県と岩手県は、**仮設住宅などには世話をする人がいないお年寄りなど生活に困っている人が住んでいることが多い**ため、１人で亡くなる人が増えていると考えています。
>   The Miyagi and Iwate prefectures think that the number of people who are dying alone is increasing because there are many cases of people living in temporary housing who struggle with daily life and have no one to take care of them.

I'm struggling to parse the part in bold in a convincing way. I'll try to break it down:

> 仮設住宅などに**人**が住んでいることが多い
>   There are many cases of people living in temporary housing.

What kind of people?

> 生活に困っている人
>   People who struggle with daily living

The part I'm stuck on is how to join all of this with

> 世話をする人がいないお年寄り
>   Old people who have no one to care for them

I don't understand how this fits with the rest of the sentence. At first I assumed that お年寄り was the subject of 困っている but then I have

> **お年寄り**が生活に困っている**人**

So the subject appears twice in this clause, both as the actual subject and the relativised (is that a word?) noun. This doesn't seem right.

What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: The second など is the key.

Comment: @mamster I figured it was, but など often ends up confusing me. I really struggle with it for some reason.

Comment: Try replacing it with の or という

Comment: Or rather adding one of those after the など

Comment: Hmm. I'm still struggling with that. Are you suggesting that という/の should modify 生活 or 人? Either way, I'm not sure this makes things clearer for me. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Although this isn't what your question asks about, Japanese does have a (marginally) grammatical construction called the Head-Internal Relative Clause, which native speakers generally don't like the sound of, so they typically only use them when they can't think of a better choice – similar to the marginal status of the resumptive pronoun in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how the phrase you're having trouble with breaks down:

> 世話をする人がいないお年寄りなど生活に困っている**人**

What type of 人？

> お年寄りなど生活に困っている**人**

"People who struggle with daily life, such as elderly people." Let's refer to these people as "subj".

What subset of these people, in particular?

> 世話をする人がいないsubj

Ones who have no one to care for them.

> 仮設住宅などには

is not part of the relative clause, as you can tell because it contains a は particle. There's no reason you couldn't rewrite it to make it a relative clause, however, and it was relativized in the English translation in this case.

Comment: "such as". That's the key phrase that makes me happy :)

Comment: Might 'etc.' make you happy as well?

Comment: In terms of analyzing the grammar, “etc.” works well, but it’s not a word that would be natural in the translation. Maybe a more faithful but still natural translation would be “and others”.